# Python script to extract specific data with Xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, extract

I would like to extract all data of the row named "Nb B" at this url page : https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php

Here is my python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php')

#Store url associated with the soccer games
url_links = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "match/cotes-")]'):
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

print(len(url_links), '\n')

nb_bookies = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(@class, " odds")][contains(@style, "")]'):
    nb_bookies.append(i.text)
    
print(nb_bookies)
```

And here is the output :

```
25 

['1.80', '3.55', '4.70', '95%', '', '1.40', '4.60', '8.00', '94.33%', '', '2.35', '3.42', '2.63', '90.18%', '', '3.20', '3.60', '2.05', '92.19%', '', '7.00', '4.80', '1.35', '90.81%', '', '5.30', '4.30', '1.70', '99.05%', '', '2.15', '3.55', '3.65', '97.92%', '', '2.90', '3.20', '2.20', '88.81%', '', '3.95', '3.40', '2.10', '97.65%', '', '2.00', '3.80', '3.90', '98.04%', '', '2.40', '3.05', '3.50', '96.98%', '', '3.70', '3.20', '2.00', '91.72%', '', '2.75', '2.52', '3.05', '91.17%', '', '4.20', '3.05', '1.69', '84.23%', '', '1.22', '5.10', '10.00', '88.42%', '', '1.54', '4.60', '5.10', '93.72%', '', '3.00', '3.10', '2.45', '93.59%', '', '2.40', '3.50', '2.55', '90.55%', '', '1.76', '3.50', '4.20', '90.8%', '', '11.50', '5.30', '1.36', '98.91%', '', '3.00', '3.50', '2.20', '92.64%', '', '1.72', '3.42', '5.00', '92.62%', '', '1.08', '9.25', '19.00', '91.33%', '', '9.75', '5.75', '1.36', '98.82%', '', '5.70', '4.50', '1.63', '98.88%', '']
```

All the data of the table is extracted and you can see '' for the last row whereas I just want the last row.

Comment: i think you mean data of column `Nb B` ?

Comment: yes that is that

Comment: @ahmedaao do see my answer and let me know how you get on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data from the last column only, fix your XPath accordingly :

```
nb_bookies = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@id and @role="row" ]/td[last()]'):
    nb_bookies.append(i.text)
```

Output :

```
['12', '12', '1', '9', '11', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '11', '2', '11', '11', '9', '12', '11', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '10', '5', '12']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine, the problem is to do with the window size that is `spawned` by the Automator in a `headless` mode. The default window size and display size in headless mode is `800x600` on all platforms.

The developers of the site have set the `header` to only appear if the width of the window is `>1030px` and only then the `display: none;` is removed from `DOM`. You can test this for yourself by shrinking & expanding the window size.

> You need to understand that if an element's attribute contains `style="display: none;"` which means the element is hidden then Selenium won't be able to interact with the element, i.e. if a user can't see it then the same behavior applies to `selenium`.

Simply adding this line to enlarge your window in a headless mode will solve your problem.

```
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
```